# Comparing two objects with "special" assertions for certain fields with AssertJ

Tags: assertj

Given the following class...

```java
public class UserAccount {
  private Long id;
  private String email;
  private String activationCode;
  private Date createDate;
}
```

... I need to compare the actual object with an expected object using AssertJ. However the fields `id`, `activationCode` and `createDate` have dynamic value which I can't hard-code into the assertion.

So the following assertion would fail:
`assertThat(actualUserAccount).isEqualTo(expectedUserAccount);`

Then I found the following which would ignore certain fields:

```java
assertThat(actualUserAccount)
        .usingRecursiveComparison()
        .ignoringFields("id", "activationCode", "createDate")
        .isEqualTo(expectedUserAccount);
```

But what I'm actually looking for is to assert for the objects being equal with the following special checks on certain fields:

- Is there an `id` with any `Long` value?
- Is there an `activationCode` with any `String` value?
- Is there an `createDate` with any `Date` value?

Or is there no other way than to write one assertion for each field?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You can specify how to compare certain fields with [withEqualsForFields](https://javadoc.io/doc/org.assertj/assertj-core/latest/org/assertj/core/api/RecursiveComparisonAssert.html#withEqualsForFields(java.util.function.BiPredicate,java.lang.String...)) so you could write something like:

```java
assertThat(actualUserAccount)
        .usingRecursiveComparison()
        .withEqualsForFields((id1, id2) -> id1 instanceof Long && id2 instanceof Long, "id")
        .isEqualTo(expectedUserAccount);
```

I'm checking both ids fields since there is no garantee that `id1` is the actual id and `id2` the expected id.

You could also write a generic method like `BiPredicate<A, B> isType(T type)` that returns a bipredicate checking both parameters are of the type T (my suggested signature might not work but you get the idea), that would let you write:

```java
assertThat(actualUserAccount)
        .usingRecursiveComparison()
        .withEqualsForFields(isType(Long.class), "id")
        .withEqualsForFields(isType(String.class), "activationCode")
        .withEqualsForFields(isType(Date.class), "createDate")
        .isEqualTo(expectedUserAccount);
```

Here's what `isType` looks like (I haven't tested it though):

```java
<A, B, T extends Class<?>> BiPredicate<A, B> isType(T type) {
    return (a, b) -> type.isInstance(a) && type.isInstance(b);
}
```

Having said that, I would probably not go that way and write additional assertions.

For reference: https://assertj.github.io/doc/#assertj-core-recursive-comparison-comparators

Answer (score 2):

If you want to verify that all the fields have a value you could use [`hasNoNullFieldsOrProperties`](https://www.javadoc.io/doc/org.assertj/assertj-core/latest/org/assertj/core/api/AbstractObjectAssert.html#hasNoNullFieldsOrProperties()), while [`returns`](https://www.javadoc.io/doc/org.assertj/assertj-core/latest/org/assertj/core/api/AbstractObjectAssert.html#returns(T,java.util.function.Function)) can be used to refine the verification of `email` (assuming that getters are exposed):

```
assertThat(actualUserAccount)
  .hasNoNullFieldsOrProperties()
  .returns(expectedUserAccount.getEmail(), from(UserAccount::getEmail));
```

If you must enforce the type of the fields, you can chain:

```
  .extracting(UserAccount::getId, UserAccount::getEmail, UserAccount::getActivationCode, UserAccount::getCreateDate)
  .hasExactlyElementsOfTypes(Long.class, String.class, String.class, Date.class);
```

If getters are not available, your original example is probably the only option to verify the value of `email`:

```
assertThat(actualUserAccount)
    .usingRecursiveComparison()
    .ignoringFields("id", "activationCode", "createDate")
    .isEqualTo(expectedUserAccount);
```

But still you can use `extracting(String...)` instead of `extracting(Function...)` to enforce the type of the fields:

```
assertThat(actualUserAccount)
  .extracting("id", "email", "activationCode", "createDate")
  .hasExactlyElementsOfTypes(Long.class, String.class, String.class, Date.class);
```

However, these options are not refactoring-friendly.

Answer (score 0):

This might not apply directly, because you were interested in any date value. But if you want to make sure that a date is "approximately exact", the use of withEqualsForType might be useful (the example uses OffsetDateTimes, but the logic is the same).
A typical example would be that you want to check that the current timestamp will be set during the method you are testing, but you can't know in advance the precise moment it will happen. You can set "now" during the test and then assert that the actual timestamp will differ from it for a certain delta at max (for example one second). If, for example, you are writing timestamps in OffsetDateTimes (if you are using Long you will probably not be able to use this method), you can do this:

```
assertThat(actualObject)
    .usingRecursiveComparison()
    .withEqualsForType(timestampAlmostEquals, OffsetDateTime.class)
    .isEqualTo(expectedObject);
```

where

```
BiPredicate<OffsetDateTime, OffsetDateTime> timestampAlmostEquals = (t1, t2) -> Math.abs(ChronoUnit.SECONDS.between(t1, t2)) < 1;
```

All the OffsetDateTime fields in the actual and expected objects will be treated as equal as long as they do not differ by more than one second.

Again, it does not apply directly to you question, but when I was looking for a solution to my problem google search pointed me to yours. So maybe it will be useful to some other lost soul :D